# Why do I need to manually pushObject after a successful hasMany create?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a hasMany / belongsTo relationship

```
App.Appointment = DS.Model.extend({
  employee: belongsTo('employee', { async: true})
});
App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
  appointments: hasMany('appointment', { async: true})
});
```

I have a simple form that lets me create the appointment

```
var appointment = {
    employee: employee (another ember-data model)
}
this.store.createRecord('appointment', appointment).save().then(function(apt) {
    self.get('target').transitionTo('day.index');
}
```

If I do the above my "employees" array never shows the inverse correctly (ie- it doesn't reflect the new appointment when I do something later like employee.get('appointments');

I've been able to "work around" this issue w/ something like the below

```
this.store.createRecord('appointment', appointment).save().then(function(apt) {
    employee.get('appointments').pushObject(apt);
    employee.save();
    self.get('target').transitionTo('day.index');
}
```

I don't like this for 2 reasons

1. I feel like if I have ember-data wired up correctly it should just
   "know" that I've added a new appointment w/ the related employee (as
   I see that going across the wire)
2. this forces a "lookup" on my hasMany (so it then fires off a request
   asking for that employees apts -often messing up the scope of "how
   many" apts I want to show for a given context).

Is my relationship setup correctly here? Or is this a bug in ember-data 1.0 beta 4/5 ?

I'm currently using ember-data 1.0 beta 4 with ember.js 1.3.1

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear, was kind of hoping the [inverses on relationships](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.html#method_hasMany) would resolve these types of issues from pre ember-data 1.0. Does it work if you explicitly specify the inverse relationship, like they suggest in the docs?

Comment: That only works for non async.  Async is a little interesting in the problem that they don't want to fetch records until you request them.  And then if you inject an item, how do you then signal you want the new records versus that one record

Comment: This is more of a predicament than a bug.  I'm not sure of the one size fits all solution.

Comment: So what's a compromise in the short term where I can manually add to the RecordArray in the didCreate (without fetching the hasMany relationship?). If I need to touch a private API until this gets some love from the core team - I'm open to it at this time

Comment: For anyone who might follow -this solved #2 above (still a hack obviously) employee.get('data').appointments.pushObject(apt);

Comment: Hey Toran! :) Yeah I've got this sort of code all through my app too... can I ask why you have aync: true set on your BT association? I didn't think it made any sense on that side. Mind you, I think perhaps I should do some more research on what async: true does, coz I'm a little shaky on that. Is the aync: true why you have to do the manual push?

Have you seen this? http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/new-hasmany-with-async/2550/3

It might clarify things for you a little?

Comment: @JulianLeviston this is worth an offline discussion for sure. In short, at this time ember-data is not build around async apis (meaning you can't POST/PUT to a child model if it's async instead of embedded). I'm running a fork to get around this (as ember-data core still hasn't pulled in a true fix for this). In the future I'm thinking about writing my own wrapper that's "async-first" as most large apps fall down when the json payload is embedded (it just gets to big w/ nested objects all inline). Contact me via gmail if you want a more indepth chat about the work around/ etc :)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is what I'm currently using to do a recursive save on my 'items'. They have children, and they have permissions associated to them. Also worth noting is that these items are recursive (so, the items can have children, which are items that can have children... and so on and so forth). This will handle the case where some of the items are saved or not including all parent re-association and what not. It works for me. This might help you (or it might just confused you completely, I hope not though.)

If you can get something useful out of it, that's great :)

Also worth noting is that I don't do anything with my error catches. This isn't ideal, obviously!

```
saveAll: function() {
  var saveExistingObjects, self;
  saveExistingObjects = function(item) {
    var promise;
    promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      return item.get('childItems').then(function(childItems) {
        var childPromises;
        childPromises = childItems.map(function(childItem) {
          return saveExistingObjects(childItem);
        });
        return Ember.RSVP.all(childPromises).then(function(arrayOfSavedChildren) {
          var itemPermissions, itemWasNew;
          itemWasNew = item.get('isNew');
          itemPermissions = item.get('itemPermissions');
          return item.save().then(function(savedItem) {
            if (itemWasNew) {
              arrayOfSavedChildren.forEach(function(childItem) {
                childItem.set('parentItem', savedItem);
                return childItem.save();
              });
              itemPermissions.forEach(function(itemPermission) {
                itemPermission.set('item', savedItem);
                return itemPermission.save();
              });
            }
            savedItem.set('childItems', []);
            Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(savedItem.get('childItems')).then(function(cb) {
              return cb.addObjects(arrayOfSavedChildren);
            });
            return resolve(savedItem);
          })["catch"](function(error) {
            console.log("Didn't save!");
            return reject(error);
          });
        })["catch"](function(error) {
          console.log("Didn't finish saveExistingObjects and returning childPromises");
          console.log(error);
          return reject(error);
        });
      })["catch"](function(error) {
        console.log("Didn't get childItems");
        console.log(error);
        return reject(error);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  };
  self = this;
  return saveExistingObjects(self);
}
```